# How to run nginx + python (without django)

Tags: python, nginx, web, fastcgi

I want to have simple program in python that can process different requests (POST, GET, MULTIPART-FORMDATA). I don't want to use a complete framework.

I basically need to be able to get GET and POST params - probably (but not necessarily) in a way similar to PHP. To get some other SERVER variables like REQUEST_URI, QUERY, etc.

I have installed nginx successfully, but I've failed to find a good example on how to do the rest. So a simple tutorial or any directions and ideas on how to setup nginx to run certain python process for certain virtual host would be most welcome!

Comment: Have you looked into flask? Super lightweight framework for building webapps

Comment: I do not need a webapp, just a simple program that processes simple request.

Comment: That's pretty much what flask is. It's an interface to a wsgi server (werkzeug) and has some templating system you can ignore.

Comment: tkone, I actually managed to run Python with nginx from the examples and explanation in the Flask page and am now using it. Please add your comment as an answer so I can accept it.

Comment: answer is added.  (ps the mailing list is a great place for help on flask)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should look into using Flask -- it's an extremely lightweight interface to a WSGI server (werkzeug) which also includes a templating library, should you ever want to use one.  But you can totally ignore it if you'd like.

Comment: Wow, Flask looks great! Exactly what I was looking for :)

Answer (score 8):

Although you can make Python run a webserver by itself with [`wsgiref`](http://docs.python.org/library/wsgiref.html#examples), I would recommend using one of the many Python webservers and/or web frameworks around. For pure and simple Python webhosting we have several options available:

- [gunicorn](https://gunicorn.org/)
- [tornado](https://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/)
- [twisted](https://twisted.org/)
- [uwsgi](https://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)
- [cherrypy](https://docs.cherrypy.dev/en/latest/)

If you're looking for more features you can look at some web frameworks:

- [werkzeug](https://werkzeug.palletsprojects.com/)
- [flask](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/)
- [masonite](https://docs.masoniteproject.com/)
- [cherrypy](https://docs.cherrypy.dev/en/latest/) (yes, cherrypy is  both a webserver and a framework)
- [django](https://www.djangoproject.com/) (for completeness, I know that was not the purpose of the question)

Comment: The site appears to be dead; here is an archive link: https://web.archive.org/web/20170810030544/http://nichol.as/benchmark-of-python-web-servers

Comment: @DoktorJ I've updated the answer which makes the link irrelevant. It's a tad outdated anyhow :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use thttpd. It is a lightweight wsgi server for running cgi scripts. It works well with nginx. How to setup thttpd with Nginx is detailed here: http://nginxlibrary.com/running-cgi-scripts-using-thttpd/

Comment: Nice solution :) It should be noted however, that using cgi is generally not really a good plan, with cgi you have to start a new process for every request which is quite slow compared to keeping the process running and letting it handle multiple requests.

Answer (score 0):

All the same you must use wsgi server, as nginx does not support fully this protocol.